# Word choice - When you use a too generic term to describe something specific

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Suppose I have a taxonomy, which describes animals, that looks like this

```
+ Animal 
  + Mammal 
    + Cat 
    + Dog
```

And I want people to use this taxonomy to label a set of 100 images of cats and dogs. Imagine that, instead of using 'cat' and 'dog', people have mostly described these images as 'animal' and 'mammal', say, for 90% of the images.

I want a word or phrase to describe this 'misuse of too generic concept', i.e., they should've used 'cat' and 'dog' that is more specific in the taxonomy to describe the data. Instead, they chose to use a more generic one that would not be as specific or as appropriate.

At the moment I just say, as above, 'misuse of too generic concept'. But is there a better and shorter way to refer to this problem? e.g., 'overuse of generic concept', but that does not seem to capture the problem here...

Comment: Do you specifically want a term for "misuse of too generic concept", or would "more generic concept" do? We say that "mammal" is a **hypernym** of "cat" and "dog". ("Hyperonym" is better formed than "hypernym", but "hypernym" seems to be used more.)

Comment: Thanks I think I could use hypernym to describe this problem, thank you!

Comment: It's ***generalization*** - or if you insist on a term implying "misuse", perhaps ***overgeneralization*** (but that may have [unwanted domain-specific implications](https://dictionary.apa.org/overgeneralization)).

Comment: If you don't mind to use some pretentious linguistic vocabulary, consider **archilexeme**

Comment: You could also switch from telling what not to do to requesting what you want - the most specific term possible. The term 'specific' is in general use and well-understood.

Comment: *_a too generic concept_ is ungrammatical. It should be _a concept too generic_. See the [many famous videos](https://www.google.com/search?q=maru+and+the+too+small+box) of "Maru and the too small box".  _Too_ is the negative version of _so_ -- instead of _so ADJ that S_, it means _so ADJ that NOT S_

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/618962/2085).

Answer (score 2):

This could be called **underspecification.** [Wiktionary defines it as:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/underspecification)

> Inadequate specification; failure to specify in enough detail.